# How to parse inbound e-mail when using Mule's IMAP transport?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am just starting to learn mule so please forgive me if this is a very basic question.

I have successfully configured mule to monitor my mail box so whenever a mail comes in I write the mail to text file (just for testing).

Now I need to parse this mail and get the message / From / To from the mail.

```
<flow name="testFlow" doc:name="testFlow">
        <imap:inbound-endpoint host="ip"
            port="143" user="username" password="pwd" doc:name="IMAP"
            responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="Message_Properties">
        </imap:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\"
            outputPattern="#[function:datestamp].dat" doc:name="File">
        </file:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
```

I thought I would be able to get the header information using the below expression (using expression transformer)

```
#[inboundProperties['email-header-name']]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. I also tried the below expressions but didn't work,

```
#[map-payload:HOST]
#[map-payload:MESSAGE]
#[map-payload:TIMESTAMP]
```

Can someone help?  Also does anyone know if there is a document with the list of available expressions?

EDIT:

I included the logger to view the properties and it displayed all the properties but I couldnt find the body.. Also, I tried getting the fromAddress using

```
#[map-payload:fromAddress] and #[inboundProperties['fromAddress']]
```

but didn't work, can someone let me know where I am wrong?

The properties are something like below,

```
inbound.fromAddress=Service <service@xx.com> 
inbound.subject=Test Final inbound.toAddresses=Service
```

Edit 2:

This is what I have tried but doesnt work :(

I am trying to retrieve the email subject and write to file or just show it using logger based on email subject but I am getting the below error.

```
ERROR 2013-02-07 19:22:45,275 [[test].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message : Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}".
Code : MULE_ERROR-236
```

Can you let me know where I am making mistake?

```
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
<imap:inbound-endpoint host="ip"
port="143" user="uname" password="pwd" doc:name="IMAP"
responseTimeout="10000" disableTransportTransformer="true">
</imap:inbound-endpoint>
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['inbound.fromAddress']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<choice doc:name="Choice">
<when expression="message.inboundProperties['inbound.subject']=='plain test'">
<processor-chain>
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['inbound.fromAddress']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</processor-chain>
</when>
<otherwise>
<processor-chain>
<file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\mule" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp].dat" responseTimeout="10000" disableTransportTransformer="true" doc:name="File">
</file:outbound-endpoint>
</processor-chain>
</otherwise>
</choice>
</flow>
```

Comment: Use #[ ] in your when expression. It works without but this is a temporary backwards compatible mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the [IMAP connector documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/IMAP+Transport+Reference) doesn't list the message properties created when a new message is received. You can find all the created properties by adding:

```
<logger level="WARN" />
```

after the `imap:inbound-endpoint`. This will log all the message meta information, including properties, at WARN level.

You can also find the property names in the [`MailProperties` JavaDoc](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/transport/email/MailProperties.html). For example `inbound.fromAddress` is the inbound property that contains the sender's email address.

The message body is the text email content, unless it's a multi-part email. In that case, if the first part is `text/plain`, it will be set as the message payload, otherwise all parts will be available as inbound message attachments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I included the logger to view the properties and it displayed all the properties but I couldnt find the body..

Also, I tried getting the fromAddress using #[map-payload:fromAddress] and #[inboundProperties['fromAddress']] but didn't work, can you let me know where I am wrong?
inbound.fromAddress=Service <service@xx.com>
    inbound.subject=Test Final
    inbound.toAddresses=EDEN Service

Comment: I renamed "payload" to "body" in my answer, as I explained already where is the body going. Use: #[message.inboundProperties['inbound.fromAddress']] (learn MEL here http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/MEL+Cheat+Sheet).

Comment: Thanks for your help...The documentation really helped me... I have updated my question with updated flow... I am still getting an error.. Can you please help me to fix this error?

Comment: Remove `disableTransportTransformer="true"`: this prevents Mule to extract the email body.