# How to transform javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage to java.io.InputStream in Mule

Tags: email, mule, transformer-model

I tried to read a file and email through Mule. But it throws the following exception.

```
  org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to    transform "SimpleDataType{type=javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}".
  at  org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:252)
  at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:355)
  at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:313)
 + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

**My mule file is as follows:**

```
<flow name="Exception_HandlingFlow1" doc:name="Exception_HandlingFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\WorkArea\COPA\In" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File Writer">
        <file:file-to-string-transformer/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <component doc:name="Java" class="com.exhnlr.Handler.ExceptionHandler"/>
    <smtps:outbound-endpoint host="192.168.131.139" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" 
        from="anbu1@bibs.com" subject="test" to="anbu1@bibs.com" user="anbu1" mimeType="text/plain">
        <email:string-to-email-transformer/>
    </smtps:outbound-endpoint>        
</flow>
```

I have read a similiar link [How to parse inbound e-mail when using Mule's IMAP transport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757677/how-to-parse-inbound-e-mail-when-using-mules-imap-transport), but it didn't work for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<object-to-string-transformer />` after the file inbound endpoint.

Comment: I tried the below.. But it still dint work...<file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\WorkArea\COPA\In" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File Writer"> <file:file-to-string-transformer/> </file:inbound-endpoint> <object-to-string-transformer /> <component doc:name="Java" class="com.exhnlr.Handler.ExceptionHandler"/> <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="192.168.131.139" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" from="anbu1@bibs.com" subject="test" to="anbu1@bibs.com" user="anbu1" mimeType="text/plain"> <email:string-to-email-transformer/> </smtp:outbound-endpoint>

Comment: Are you getting the same exception? What is the output of your custom component?